# How Does Feedly Parse the Images from this RSS Feed?

Tags: json, api, rss, feed, feedly

I have a feed that I'd like to extract to content of the posts from: http://feeds.feedburner.com/oogionet

I'd like to parse each post **title**, **publish date** and **feature image**.  I have a problem with this feed because it doesn't contain the feature images, so as far as I understand - I can't parse them...

However, when I try to get the feed contents using **Feedly**, like this: https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?count=5&streamId=feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/oogionet, the images **do** appear in it (in each `visual` node).

So I'd like to ask, how do they do it? This feed doesn't contain the posts' images so how can **Feedly** get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Feedly crawls the HTML page (https://www.oogio.net/?p=26620 for the first item), and looks for [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) content. When viewing the source for that page, you'll see a `<meta>` tag like this:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.oogio.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/chocolate_rice_krispies_snack2-s.jpg" />`

This tag is used by providers like Slack and Facebook to show images on posts, and I'm pretty sure that it's how Feedly gets the image.